# How to make a batch file using CMD?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

Can someone please tell me how I can create a batch file (empty) using CMD? I tried below, didn't work.

```
echo  C:\Users\Yohan\Desktop\test > test.bat
```

Answer (score 4):

From your command prompt:

```
type NUL>test.bat
```

or

```
copy NUL test.bat
```

Here `NUL` *does not* refer to the `ASCII NUL` (character of ASCII integer value zero). It's a system reserved word for `NUL` device (imagine a *fake file* of zero length).

Answer (score 2):

```
echo.>>mybatchfile.bat
```

Note that this will create a file containing a single newline.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **Create** the file in  **C:\Users\Yohan\Desktop\test**

First use the **CD** command to change the current directory, then try. or else it will create in **system32** (if you run the cmd from accessories)

Try the below :

**>** `cd  C:\Users\Yohan\Desktop\test`  then

**>** `echo empty >a.bat`

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

From your command prompt:

```
copy con test.bat
[ctrl]+z
```

The [ctrl]+z is the End of File marker, closing and saving the empty file.

Basically, you are just copying with the source being the CONsole and the destination being the .BAT file.

Comment: This method also allows you to add commands to the batch file if desired.  Just enter each command on a new line and press [ENTER].  When finished, enter [ctrl]+z on a new line to close and save it.

Answer (score 1):

just to add another possibility to create an empty file (0 Byte):

```
break>mybatchfile.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept behind the creation of an empty file is simple: take *nothing* and put it in a file. A way to do that is using a command that produce no output and redirect its output to the file, so you just need to know which commands produce no output.

In the old MS-DOS command.com days, that command was `rem`:

```
rem Create an empty file > empty.txt
```

However, such functionality was removed in Windows cmd.exe. Other commands that show nothing and works in Windows are:

```
break > empty.txt
call > empty.txt
cd . > empty.txt
color > empty.txt
endlocal > empty.txt
setlocal > empty.txt
shift > empty.txt
title > empty.txt
verify off > empty.txt
```

The problem with these commands is that they do a certain task, so using they to create an empty file seems strange. For example, `goto` command also show nothing:

```
goto nextLine > empty.txt
:nextLine
```

Another example:

```
(if a == b echo Create an empty file) > empty.txt
```

Other command that show nothing is `exit`, so you may write a subroutine that create an empty file with the name given in its parameter this way:

```
:CreateEmptyFile
exit /B > %1
```

So, which command should we use? Well, in my particular case I prefer that the purpose of the command be perfectly clear, so I choose an auto-documented `set` command:

```
set dummyVar=Create an empty file > empty.txt
```